HTTP request gets 404 ... should get a 403
I'm getting a few 404s and can't figure out why.
My .htaccess looks like:
# boatload of Deny from IPs

<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /
  
  # Block most requests to mydomain.com
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/403\.shtml$
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com$ [NC,OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
  RewriteRule .* - [R=403,L]

# more stuff

This is an area of my shared hosting account that should not be accessible to the www. I'd like any request (other than /403.shtml) to get a 403.
Yet I find this singular 404 in my Apache access log...
apache access log
I'm probably missing something obvious. I occasionally see a few other 404s (not in this particular log file), but mostly I get the expected 403s.
This isn't a big deal. But if I am doing something wrong I'd like to find out.
Any suggestions?
